# Ice maker not working

Tags: ice-maker

I have a whirlpool model wrf540cwhv00 and the ice maker has stopped working.

I have checked for stuck ice and verified  that  the water line is not frozen. I have tried to reset it by putting the wire between the H and T ports, this did not work.   I then  took my wife's hair dryer to the front and tried this again and it ran a cycle but needed a little bit of help to turn the gear.

It filled with water and froze again but the cycle to thaw and eject has not started after a few hours.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ice makers in refrigerators are junk in my opinion, not made to last, prior to a sub zero that had a separate replaceable unit when they died I just got one of those 150$ counter top models and dumped the ice into the bin, cheaper and less headache than replacing the cheap garbage installed these days.

Comment: Are you saying the ice maker makes ice, but fails to eject the ice cubes so that another batch can begin? Have you tested the heat element to confirm that it works?

Comment: no It makes ice and I can get the heat cycle to run but for some reason the gear will not turn on its own to complete a full cycle, but if I give it very minimal help turning it will work